# Android's ContentResolver.isSyncActive returns false before the actual sync is over

Tags: android, android-volley, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter, swiperefreshlayout

I am triggering a sync with a REST service using SwipeRefreshLayout's onRefresh method by calling ContentResolver.requestSync, which launches my Syncadapter. 
The Syncadapter then uses Volley's Request to communicate with the server.

To detect the end of the sync operation and close the activity indicator I use ContentResolver.isSyncActive inside SyncStatusObserver of the Fragment from which I initiated the sync.

The problem is that the ContentResolver.isSyncActive returns false before the actual sync with the server is over, causing the activity indicator to disappear almost immediately.

Am I correct assuming that the asynchronous nature of Volley's Request causes the SyncAdapter's onPerformSync to return immediately which, in turn, makes the ContentResolver think that the sync is over?

If yes, what is the correct/recommended solution here? I can come up with workarounds, but wanted to make sure I am not missing something obvious.

I have looked through many examples including iosched, swiperefresh, basicsyncadapter etc., but they all seem to "hold" the onPerformSync method until everything is over.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should make the requests act synchronously inside the onPerformSync method. I use Retrofit for calls with backends but I think Volley should also provide the synchronous functionality.